# Queries executing in orders

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about queries. Does queries get execute in orders? For example, the query below:

```
SELECT colName1 from table where colName1 = 'a' and colName2 = 'b' limit 1
```

Does it select all the rows where colName1 = 'a', and then from all the rows where colName1 = 'a', it selects all the rows where colName2 = 'b'? Or does it do it all at once? If the first is true, then depending on how many rows of 'a' and 'b' there are, and the order they are written in, the query could take shorter or longer time to execute.

For example, if in the table, there are 1,000,000 rows where colName1 = 'a', and 1 row where colName2 = 'b', then:

```
1. First it would search the table for where colName1 = 'a'. 
2. It would return 1,000,000 results.
3. Then in those 1,000,000 results, it would search for colName2 = 'b'.
4. Then it would return 1 result.
```

If colName2 were searched first, then it would be faster:

```
1. First it would search the table for where colName2 = 'b'. 
2. It would return 1 result.
3. Then in that 1 result, it would search for colName1 = 'a'.
4. Then it would return 1 result.
```

^---Of course, that would only be true, if both colName1 and colName2 aren't executed at the same time. So, which is it? Does queries get executed in steps like the above?

Comment: @KaeL Accepted answer basically said something like, I have no idea, but you should do some experimentation to find the answer. Guess, I'll just try to write the queries in optical orders anyway.

Comment: @frosty The answer say optimzer will choose the best way. Very intelligent ppl work on those optimzer and usually do a great job specially because they create statistic just for that.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza He said that it depends on the optimizer, and that it shouldn't matter, emphasizing on the 'shouldn't', implying, in fact, that he isn't too sure, but hopes that the people who worked on the engine does in fact make it so that orders doesn't affect the speed too much. And that the only way to know for sure, is to do your own experimentation.

Comment: Yes, pretty much that.